# URLConnection with Parameters

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

Before i used the Apache Library(org.apach.httpclient) to make a Request to a Php Script with Parameters(BasicNameValuePair),

Then Now i want to remove those Libraries to Decrease The APK Size & also because it's Deprecated,

I have tried many Solutions & Many Examples & No One of them worked,

This is The Code i use Actually(nothing happens) :

```
public JSONObject sendRequest(final String link, final HashMap<String, String> values) {
    JSONObject object = null;
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

    HttpURLConnection conn;
    final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15 * 1000;
            Log.e("Tag", "Start");
    try {
        URL url = new URL(link);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.connect();
        Log.e("Tag", "Connect");
        if (values != null) {
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(osWriter);
            Log.e("Tag", "Write " + values);
            writer.write(getPostData(values));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
        }

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {}
    catch (IOException e) {}

        }

};
thread.start();
    return object;
}
```

Call sendRequest() :

```
    HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
    values.put("Test01", "Test");
    values.put("Test02", "Test2");
    sendRequest("http://TheWebSite/script.php", values);
```

The Php Script should simply write the value in a File but Nothing Happens(it's worked with the Apache HttpPost),

Any Solutions ?

Thanks

Comment: what it returns, `null` or anything else??

Comment: @ELITE this should not return anything to Android, it's a kind of "Analytic" system, the php script write to a file in the Server that's all

Comment: print all your exceptions..you're handling exceptions but not printing it..

Comment: try `conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/json");` and send values as JSON instead of `HashMap`

Comment: @ELITE the log says that the URL Connect & the values are Correctly written

Comment: @Ashish Tiwari the same happens(Nothing)

Comment: update code with printing statistics..like `catch (MalformedURLException e) { Log.e("tag", Log.getStackTrace(e)); }`...

Comment: @ELITE There is No Trace, This is what i use in the Php Script : $_REQUEST['Test']

Comment: here is the error...you have to replace it with `$_POST['Test']`...It'll surely solve your issue...

Comment: @ELITE Thanks for pointing this Error, but this does not seem to be the main cause... do you have a "ready to use" code for posting two parameters ?

Comment: Yep I have.will post it in answer.

Answer (score 1):

I Have Resolved My Issue by using This :

```
           String data = "";
           try{
                data = URLEncoder.encode("Test01", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Test02", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");
            }
           catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           }
```

Instead of The HashMap String,

I have also Followed The Recommandation from The Android Developer Doc about The Compatibility :

```
        if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
      }
```

It's also important to Get The Response Code When Debugging(mine was 200 OK) :

```
int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
Log.e("Tag", "Response Code " + String.valueOf(responseCode));
```

Thanks To @ELITE For your Help & your Recommandation about using $_POST instead of $_REQUEST,

Thanks